# OSX El Capitan Unable to add exchange account

Tags: mac, keychain, exchange

I had a problem with Lync because of which I went to Keychain Access > Preferences > Reset My Default Keychain.

After that all of my passwords were reset and I had to enter them again. When I was trying to enter the password for my EXCHANGE accounts, it didn't work and I deleted these accounts (hoping i can recreate them).

Once I try to recreate the EXCHANGE accounts, it will connect with the server and then show the option of Mail, Calendar, Notes, Reminders. Once I click DONE, the spinner spins but nothing happens and I can only cancel to go out. The accounts aren't created.

This is happening for both exchange accounts.

I went to CONSOLE and checked the log files and I found this entry:

```
7/20/15 4:46:56.840 PM com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice[586]: __56-[ACUIViewController persistVerifiedAccountWithActions:]_block_invoke_3:103 -- *** Failed: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=13 "Unable to store credential due to error -25291 Requested By: 586" UserInfo=0x7fe8fed589e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to store credential due to error -25291 Requested By: 586, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe8fea22120 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts.keychain error -25291.)"}
```

From the error, it seems to be a keychain error because the package com.apple.accounts.keychain is involved in it.

Any idea on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to ask your question. Unfortunately we do not allow per-released products questions.